Always showing a window above standard 'on top' windows
I have two windows that I always need to be unobscured, even against windows that have alwaysOnTop.
The alwayOnTop subcommand is not full proof, for example if another window that also has alwaysOnTop happens to be active, it can obscure a window that also has alwaysOnTop, and then there are system windows (start, notifications) that seem to be above standard 'on top' windows
Searching a round there seems to be a way to do this, something to do with "zband" but its not well known and its to do with DLL calls, something I don't know much about.
Apparently a few people figured out it, for example malcev and teadrinker.
I tried to rework malcev's example, Alaways on Top Windows 10, and test it on a notepad window:
hwnd := DllCall("CreateWindowInBand", "uint", 0, "str", "Notepad", "str", "Untitled - Notepad", "uint", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 200, "int", 200, "ptr", 0, "ptr", 0, "ptr", 0, "ptr", 0, "int", ZBID_UIACCESS := 2, "ptr")
if !a_lasterror
    WinShow ahk_id %hwnd%
else 
    msgbox % a_lasterror

But when I run the code with a UI access interpreter, I keep getting a 1407 error, from searching around this is a "class not found error", but Spy says the class is Notepad...
I have tried to solve this on my own but examples are sparse and I am not getting anywhere, I would appreciate any pointers or solutions. Thanks.
